# Como saber si un registro ya existe antes de actualizarlo usando SQLite en Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

usando el SQLite en Android tengo un programa donde me pide el nombre, telefono y direccion, y tambien tengo un boton "Actualizar" para actualizar algunos datos, mi pregunta es:

Como creo una sentencia donde presione el boton "Actualizar" y este busque primero si existe el registro, y si existe que lo actualice. 
En caso no encuentre el registro que lo registre.

Intenté poner el contenido del metodo "Actualizar" en un try{}catch{} e incluir el metodo registrar dentro del catch pero cuando corro la aplicacion este nunca entra al catch.

Aqui dejo mi codigo de como actualizar un usuario que si existe, y tambien de como registrar un usuario , ¿Como podria unir ambos codigos para obtener el resultado que deseo? Muchas Gracias

```
 private void actualizarUsuario() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] parametros={campoId.getText().toString()};
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE,campoNombre.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_TELEFONO,campoTelefono.getText().toString());

    db.update(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO,values,Utilidades.CAMPO_ID+"=?",parametros);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ya se actualizÃ³ el usuario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
}


 //METODO PARA REGISTRAR USUARIO
   private void registrarUsuarios() {
    ConexionSQLiteHelper conn=new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this,"bd_usuarios",null,1);

    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_ID,campoId.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE,campoNombre.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_TELEFONO,campoTelefono.getText().toString());

    Long idResultante=db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO,Utilidades.CAMPO_ID,values);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Id Registro: "+idResultante,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no tengo idea de cuáles serían los nombres de tus campos de tu base de datos, pero podrías utilizar un `Cursor` para consultar tu registro y con un `if` harías el proceso de actualizar. Por ejemplo:

```
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tuTabla WHERE nombre=LeMandasElNombre and id!=ElIdDelRegistroParaActualizar", null);

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) { Si el cursor tiene un registro, quiere decir que ya existe.
         Toast.makeMessage(this, "Ya existe un registro con ese nombre", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else { Sino tiene un registro, entonces actualizamos 
        Aquí metes el código para actualizar el registro
    } 
cursor.close(); //Cerramos nuestro cursor
db.close(); //Cerramos nuestro el db
```

La lógica de la consulta es que harás un `select` para buscar el registro, los parámetros del `WHERE` son el `nombre` y el `Id` del registro que quieres actualizar, el nombre lo igualamos al nombre que acaban de ingresar como nuevo, y el Id sería diferente del registro que quieres actualizar, de esta manera el `select` buscará todos aquellos registros que tengan el dato `Nombre` pero que sean diferentes del Id que quieres actualizar.

Comment: Si funciono! Muchas Gracias

Comment: De nada camarada

Comment: Amigo y si deseo saber si existe un registro usando como parametro de busqueda 2 valores, es decir, SELECT nombre FROM miTabla where telefono ==993350485 && Direccion == Jr.España 285.  (la ultima parte no se si se escribe asi, jeje soy nuevo en esto) Gracias

Comment: Aqui el codigo que estoy intentando :      String[] parametros={elemento,ubicacion};                                                                                            Cursor 
cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT procedimiento FROM tablaacero WHERE elemento=,ubicacion=? ",parametros);

Comment: Recuerda que es solo un '=' y no dos, pero es correcto, tendrías que poner todos los campos que sean igual a los datos, y el Id que sea diferente del actual, para que busque en el resto de los registros.

Comment: String[] parametros={elemento,ubicacion,Id}; Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT procedimiento FROM tablaacero WHERE elemento=? AND ubicacion=? AND Id!=?",parametros);